# Keystore generation Entrust HSM not working

Tags: java, corretto, hardware-security-module, nshield

I am trying to set up an Entrust HSM Connect with the JCE/JCA Provider.

I've completed all the steps in the Guide (https://nshielddocs.entrust.com/connect-ug/12.80/application-interfaces) and now i struggle at "Application Interfaces". I've completed all the parts until generating a new key.

When I prompt the '`..InstallationTest`' it says that nCipher is correctly installed and is on position 1.

But when i try

```
java --module-path /opt/nfast/java/classes sun.security.tools.keytool.Main -genkey -storetype nCipher.sworld -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA -storepass <KeyStore_passphrase> -keystore <KeyStore_path>
```

It prints the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.ncipher.nfast.NFKeyModuleObjectTracker (in module com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM) cannot access class java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport (in module java.desktop) because module com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM does not read module java.desktop
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.nfast.NFKeyModuleObjectTracker.<init>(NFKeyModuleObjectTracker.java:48)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.nfast.NFKeyModuleObjectTracker.<clinit>(NFKeyModuleObjectTracker.java:23)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.nfast.NFKeyModuleObject.notifyLoaded(NFKeyModuleObject.java:31)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.nfast.NFKeyModuleObject.<init>(NFKeyModuleObject.java:26)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.km.nfkm.Key.setKeyIDs(Key.java:1557)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.km.nfkm.KeyGenerator._generateKey(KeyGenerator.java:1428)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.km.nfkm.KeyGenerator.generateUnrecordedKey(KeyGenerator.java:964)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM.generateKey(nCipherKM.java:728)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.provider.km.KMHmacSHA1KeyGenerator.engineGenerateKey(KMHmacSHA1KeyGenerator.java:58)
        at com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM/com.ncipher.provider.km.KMKeyStore.engineLoad(KMKeyStore.java:692)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:987)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:412)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:405)
```

I am using the Amazon Corretto Java version, maybe this is the problem? But normally Corretto is compatible with the Oracle version?

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I already tried a lot of things but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to `--add-modules=java.desktop --add-reads com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM=java.desktop`?

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans thanks for the hint, i saw another stackoverflow post in the meantime where this has also been recommended. It sort of helped with that particular problem but then another error occured. I was able to fix it using a different command that was not mentioned that way in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by simpling giving the command `keytool -genkey -alias <keyalias> -keyalg <algorithm> -sigalg <signingAlgorithm> -keysize <keysize> -keystore nCipher.sworld`

That created the keystore like i wanted - sadly this was not mentioned in the manual.